# create array of days in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to create an array of results, to create an easy example a reduce my function.

```
  let startDate = new Date("2022-04-05"); // starting date
  let endDate = new Date("2022-04-06"); // ending date
  let result = await cycleThroughDays(startDate, endDate);
  console.log("result", result)

async function cycleThroughDays(startDate, endDate) {
        let res = [];

    for (let currentDate = startDate; currentDate <= endDate; currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1)) {
       console.log(currentDate)
       res.push(currentDate);             
}
console.log(res)
return res;

        
}
```

The output is:

```
2022-04-05T00:00:00.000Z
2022-04-06T00:00:00.000Z
[ 2022-04-07T00:00:00.000Z, 2022-04-07T00:00:00.000Z ]
result [ 2022-04-07T00:00:00.000Z, 2022-04-07T00:00:00.000Z ]
```

I expect an array like

```
result [ 2022-04-05T00:00:00.000Z, 2022-04-06T00:00:00.000Z ]
```

but I get

```
result [ 2022-04-07T00:00:00.000Z, 2022-04-07T00:00:00.000Z ]
```

Comment: you are pushing in the array an object that you are going to change in the for afterthought. So in the array you have the same instance in multiple slots. You should instead clone the object that you are going to push in the array so that each slot will be a different instance of date like this `res.push(new Date(currentDate));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate variable to hold the current date, and increment that variable within the loop. Try this.

```
let startDate = new Date("2022-04-05"); // starting date
let endDate = new Date("2022-04-06"); // ending date
let result = await cycleThroughDays(startDate, endDate);
console.log("result", result)

async function cycleThroughDays(startDate, endDate) {
    let res = [];
    let current = new Date(startDate);

    while (current <= endDate) {
        console.log(current);
        res.push(current);
        current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
    }
    console.log(res);
    return res;
}
```